# Why am I getting a 'int object is not callable' error in my pyomo model constraint?

Tags: python, pyomo

My relevant code snippet:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

startday_index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
transport_index=[0,1,2]
routes_index=[0,1,2,3]

model = ConcreteModel()
model.routes=pyo.Set(initialize=range(4))
model.transport=pyo.Set(initialize=range(3))
model.startday=pyo.Set(initialize=range(7))

model.x=pyo.Var(routes_index,transport_index,startday_index,bounds=(0,1),within=Integers)

def rule1(model,i):
    return sum(model.x[i,j,k] for j in transport_index for k in startday_index)==1

#Constraint implemented
model.C1=Constraint(routes_index, rule=rule1)
```

I am getting this error: Constructing component 'C1_index_1' from data=None failed: TypeError: 'int' object is not
callable.

I have constructed every single object correctly taking care that the names don't end up clashing.

I have also tried replacing the routes_index with model.routes, transport_index with model.transport and startday_index with model.startday, obviously then replacing the commas in pyo.Var with *. It still gave the same error.

Complete image of the error

[image]

Comment: First, try `model.C1=Constraint(routes_index, rule=rule1)`.  If that doesn't help, then please show us the entire traceback.

Comment: @TimRoberts this was how I did for the first time. Did not work. Here is the error btw.

Comment: What does `print(type(sum))` show?

Comment: @NickODell I did not understand. The sum is not a variable. It is a callable function here. Where would like me to check print(type(sum))?

Comment: `It is a callable function here.` That's the assumption I'd like to check ;)

Comment: @NickODell I will check. But where should I check it. If I put this statement after the return function, it will not print.

Comment: @SauhaardBatra Try putting it before the return function.

Comment: Oh yeah, it printed <class 'int'>. But how??

Comment: Btw, I overloaded the sum function. It worked!! Thank you so much!